# A PHP Error: Only variables should be passed by reference in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm stuck in this error. Can someone help me out? I am using `Codeigniter 3.1.10`

Here's a snippet of my code in `system/core/Common.php`

```
function &load_class($class, $directory = 'libraries', $param = NULL)
{
    static $_classes = array();

    // Does the class exist? If so, we're done...
    if (isset($_classes[$class]))   
    {
        return $_classes[$class];
    }

    $name = FALSE;

    // Look for the class first in the local application/libraries folder
    // then in the native system/libraries folder
    foreach (array(APPPATH, BASEPATH) as $path)
    {
        if (file_exists($path.$directory.'/'.$class.'.php'))
        {
            $name = 'CI_'.$class;

            if (class_exists($name, FALSE) === FALSE)
            {
                require_once($path.$directory.'/'.$class.'.php');
            }

            break;
        }
    }
```

I keep on receiving this error message:

> Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference in
>   /customers/5/d/b/tsoft.se/httpd.www/kanban/system/codeigniter/Common.php
>   on line 148

A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice

Message: `Only variables should be passed by reference`

Filename: `codeigniter/Common.php`

Line Number: 148

> **Note : Line 148 is this `return $_classes[$class];`

Comment: usually it's your file that trigger this error message, not CodeIgniter core file. Could you provide the controller or the model in which this error occurred?

Comment: This error comes just after the installation of CI or after you did some code ?

Comment: Are you sure the error is not on line `if (isset($_classes[$class]))`? What type of variable is `$class`?

Comment: @MayankPandeyz after I did some code

Answer (score 0):

As stated in a comment on [this github issue](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/issues/5224#issuecomment-334082036), since you are using CodeIgniter version `3.1.10`, you need to replace your system folder.
The file `system/codeigniter/Common.php` has been moved to `system/core/Common.php` on your version.

Comment: I've already done that. Now, the Common.php file is already in system/core folder

Comment: okay, now why are you having this error : *Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference in /customers/5/d/b/tsoft.se/httpd.www/kanban/system/codeigniter/Common.php on line 148*? the new `system` folder doesn't have `codeigniter` folder, it's moved to `core` folder